# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_auth'

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework, pipenv, django-rest-auth

I am using docker and pipenv for my virtual environment and I am getting the following error when I run docker-compose up:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_auth'
```

I tried `pip install django-rest-auth` and `pipenv install django-rest-auth` and also added the following to my INSTALLED_APPS

```
    # Django REST Framework Apps
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
```

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    # Other Package Apps
    "storages",
    # Django REST Framework Apps
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    # Internal Apps
    "authentication",

]
```

Expected to run docker container and access backend on localhost:8000

Actual: docker-compose up > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_auth'

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib && \
    apt-get clean

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/

RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system

ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    web_app)
        until psql postgres://postgres:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@db -c '\q'; do
            >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
            sleep 1
        done

        >&2 echo "Postgres is up!"
        case "$2" in
            migrate)
                python manage.py migrate
            ;;
            static)
                python manage.py collectstatic --clear --noinput
                python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
            ;;
            migrate_and_static)
                python manage.py migrate
                python manage.py collectstatic --clear --noinput
                python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
            ;;
        esac

        case "$3" in
            prod)
                echo "Starting Gunicorn."
                exec gunicorn service_health.wsgi:application \
                    --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
                    --workers 3 \
                    --access-logfile '-'
            ;;
            local)
                pipenv install --system
                echo "Starting local server"
                python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
            ;;
        esac
    ;;
esac
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.1
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
  api:
    build: 
      context: backend
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - $PWD/backend:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    links:
      - postgres:db
    command: web_app migrate local
  frontend:
    build:
      context: frontend
    volumes:
      - $PWD/frontend:/code
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Comment: Can you please post Dockerfile and/or any docker related config? Thanks

Comment: Ok. See main post. Thank you.

Comment: a) can you show your Pipfile? b) what will became if you change `RUN pipenv install --system` to `RUN pipenv install django-rest-auth --system` - I understand that's not what you intend but for the sake of experiment, c) can you try to change `python manage.py runserver` to `pipenv run manage.py runserver`?

Answer (score -1):

### I had same error and did like this:

First I did:

> pip uninstall django-rest_auth

then:

> pip3 install django-rest_auth.

Hope this works.